# Failed authentication for user when typing psql in the terminal (mac)

Tags: macos, postgresql

Disclaimer: I looked into numerous StackOverFlow posts, but none of them helped me solving the issue :/
And I'm running this on mac Sierra

I'm trying to access PostgreSQL in the terminal by typing `psql`.
Whenever I type `psql`, I get a following error:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "JohnSmith"
password retrieved from file "/Users/JohnSmith/.pgpass"
```

In .pgpass file, here is the content:

```
localhost:(portnumber):*:JohnSmith:(password)
localhost:(portnumber):*:postgres:(password)
```

I confirm that the password for JohnSmith in pgpass is same as my Mac user password.

Can anyone guess what I'm doing wrong here?